# Does $\exists\ n$ such that the first $2n$ digits of Thue Morse, $X_{2n},$ is the concatenated sequence $X_n X_n?$ If not then why not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, binary, natural-numbers

*Background*:

> The [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) is the binary sequence (an infinite
> sequence of $0$s and $1$s) obtained by starting with $0$ and
> successively appending the Boolean complement of the sequence obtained
> thus far. The first few steps of this procedure yield the strings $0$
> then $01, 0110, 01101001, 0110100110010110,$ and so on, which are
> prefixes of the Thue–Morse sequence. The full sequence begins:
>
> $01101001100101101001011001101001....$

For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $X_n$ be the (string of) *first* $n$ digits of the Thue-Morse sequence.

> Does $\ \exists\ n\ $ such that the (string of) first $2n$ digits of T-M is the
> concatenated sequence/string $X_n X_n\ ?$

If yes, then obviously by definition of T-M, $n\neq 2^k,\ k\in\mathbb{N}$. I also know that the T-M sequence contains no cubes, i.e. concatenated contiguous subsequences of the form $XXX.$ Other than this observation, I don't see how to make progress on the problem. I have checked this up until $n=2^{13}\approx 8000$ and I have found no such $n,$ which makes me suspect the answer is "no." But the fact that the T-M sequence does contain "squares" in general (not necessarily from the first digit like in the question above), does make me wonder why the answer to the above question could be *no*, if that is in fact the answer.

Below is some code. I found the code that generates the T-M sequence with a quick google search, and the rest of the code - which is trying to find an example to the problem above - I wrote myself.

```
# Python3 Program to find nth term of
# Thue-Morse sequence.

# Return the complement of the
# binary string.
def complement(s):
    comps = "";

    # finding the complement
    # of the string.
    for i in range(len(s)): 

        # if character is 0, append 1
        if (s[i] == '0'):
            comps += '1';

        # if character is 1, append 0.
        else:
            comps += '0';

    return comps;

# Return the nth term of 
# Thue-Morse sequence.
def nthTerm(n):

    # Initializing the string to 0
    s = "0";

    # Running the loop for n - 1 time.
    for i in range(1, n): 

        # appending the complement of 
        # the string to the string.
        s += complement(s);
 
    return s;

# Driver Code


n = 15;
print(nthTerm(n))
tM_List = nthTerm(n)
print(tM_List)

for i in range(2**(n-2)):
    #print(i, list(tM_List[:i+1])),
    #print(i, list(tM_List[i+1:2*i+2])),
    if list(tM_List[:i+1]) == list(tM_List[i+1:2*i+2]):
        print('success')
```

Comment: A quick observation before I head to bed: the Thue-Morse sequence has a self-similarity, where if you replace each $0$ with $01$ and each $1$ with $10$, you obtain the Thue-Morse sequence once again. Thus, if we have $X_{2n} = X_n X_n$ for some even $n$, then this replacement, done in reverse, would yield $X_n = X_{n/2} X_{n/2}$. Therefore, if we have $X_{2n} = X_n X_n$, then the smallest such $n$ must be odd.

Answer (score 4):

It cannot happen, for reasons I discussed in my comment. Let $T_n$ be the $n$th bit of the Thue-Morse sequence $T$.

First, we have the self-similarity property: that replacing $0$ with $01$ and $1$ with $10$ in $T$ will produce $T$ once more. Looking at it in reverse, it also implies that $T$ is a sequence of $01$s and $10$s, the order of which is once again essentially $T$. Also note that this implies $T_{2k-1}\neq T_{2k}$ for any $k$. $(\ast)$

Now, if $n$ is even, we can rewrite as $X_{4n} = X_{2n}X_{2n}$, by reversing this similarity property, we then see that $X_{2n} = X_n X_n.$
By successively eliminating factors of $2$ from $n$, we can assume without loss of generality that $n$ is odd.

As you have verified, and as can be clearly seen, $n \ge 3$.

Since $X_{2n} = X_nX_n$ and $T$ begins $01$, we have $T_{n+1}=T_1=0$ and $T_{n+2}=T_2=1$. Now $(\ast)$ with $2k=n+3$ implies $T_{n+3}\neq T_{n+2}$, so $T_{n+3}=0$. Since $n\ge 3$, we have $T_3=0$.

In other words, $T$ begins $010$. But, of course, this is simply not how the Thue-Morse sequence begins. It begins $011$, which means we have our contradiction. No such $n$ exists.